# Comparing a big file on two servers

Tags: linux, centos

I have two servers and I want to move a backup tar.bz file(50G) from one to other one.

I used AXEL to download file from source server. But now when I want to extract it, it gives me error `unexpected EOF`. The size of them are same and it seems like there is a problem in content.

I want to know if there is a program/app/script that can compare these two files and correct only damaged parts?! Or do I need to split it by hand and compare each part's hash code?

Problem is here that source server has limited bandwidth and low transfers speed so I cant transfer it again from zero.

Comment: You might consider using `rsync` at least in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found "rdiff" the best way to solve this problem. Just doing:

On Destination Server:

```
rdiff signature destFile.tar.bz destFile.sig
```

Then transferring destFile.sig to source server and execute rdiff there on Source Server again:

```
rdiff delta destFile.sig srcFile.tar.bz delta.rdiff
```

Then transferring delta.rdiff to destination server and execute rdiff once again on Destination Server:

```
rdiff patch destFile.tar.bz delta.rdiff fixedFile.tar.bz
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a checksum utility, such as md5 or sha, to see if the files are the same on either end.  e.g.

```
$ md5 somefile 
MD5 (somefile) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

by running such a command on both ends and comparing the result, you can get some certainty as to if the files are the same.

As for only downloading the erroneous portion of a file, this would require checksums on both sides for "pieces" of the data, such as with the [bittorrent protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent#Description).

Comment: I know that. I want to know if there is an app to do it for me or not. Comparing files on both side and transfer only needed parts I mean.

Answer (score 1):

This process really doesn't need a separate program.  You can simply do it by using a couple of simple commands.  If any of the md5sums don't add up, copy over the mismatched one(s) and concatenate them back together.  To make comparing the md5sums easier, just run a diff between the output of the two files (or do an md5sum of the outputs to see if there is a difference at all without having to copy over the output).

```
split -b 1000000000 -d bigfile bigfile.
for i in bigfile.*
do
   md5sum $i
done
```